# "incompatible architecture" when referencing python runtime to c# program

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, python.net

I'm trying to creat a python API for a c# program to use with PythonNet, and I'm using an ARM Mac.

Here is my c# code

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

class Apitest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        string pyPath = @"/Users/coulson/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.9";
            Runtime.PythonDLL = pyPath;
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic ssearchAPI = Py.Import("ssearch");
            ssearchAPI.init();  // Call init first
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to reference the python path to the c# program, it always complains the following error

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Could not load /Users/coulson/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 with flags RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL: dlopen(/Users/coulson/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/coulson/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

But if I type $ which python3.9  in my terminal, this is indeed the python I'm using on my Mac, then how is it possible the compiler says "incompatible architecture"?

Comment: what python.net version are you using? Could be that python.net version isn't compatible. Also look at your ld_library_path (if it's set) and other environment params like xdg_data_home , xdg_config_home, etc.